# javascript variable references

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

ok so I have a variable that I set to another variable which is a javascript object.

```
function Test(){
    this.root = {"data":"mydata"};
}

Test.prototype.test = function(){
    var current = this.root;
    current = null;
    console.log(this.root);

}

var t = new Test();
t.test();
```

I have current pointing to this.root and then I reset current to null but this.root is still pointing to the javascript object.  Is it possible to also set this.root to null using the current variable?

Comment: You are only assigning `null` to `current`, not to `this.root`. Assign `null` or `current` to `this.root`.

Comment: Will like to see the scenario, you know `this.root` inside `test()` and you are simply creating `current` sort of alias to it, and trying to nullify `this.root` through it. That doesnt makes any sense of intentions behind doing so, since you can nullify `this.root` only. Do you plan to send `current` to some method and nullify it inside that method to have `this.root` nullified? Is there any other scenario specific reasons behind trying to do so?

Answer (score 0):

The correct code would be as below. You can change the property of the referenced object not the referenced object itself .

```
Test.prototype.test = function() {
            var current = this;

            current.root = null;

            console.log(this.root);

        }

        var t = new Test();
        t.test();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do change `this.root` using `current`, `current` as well as `this.root` are just references to the object.

I like the way Marijn Haverbeke explains it in [Eloquent Javascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html#p1d46b0ecd273d88c):

> You should imagine variables as tentacles, rather than boxes. They do not contain values, they grasp them ― two variables can refer to the same value. Only the values that the program still has a hold on can be accessed by it.

So they are both just grasping the object, one reference cannot change the other